# Need help retrieving some data from MySQL

Tags: php, html, mysql, explode, implode

i have a database on MySQL, which i am currently working with 3 tables.
One with emails, one with categories, and a connecting table which only has category IDs and the list of ID's of emails associated to each category, which have been imploded by PHP and are separated with " - "
For example: 2 - 5 - 4 and such and such.
I am trying to output that list of emails. First i bring the category email from another page by post, and then i use it to fetch the string of emails from the connecting table, and try to print out the emails from the email table after exploding that list. But i am getting an error. Anny help on this please?

```
<?php
mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die("problema na conexao");
mysql_select_db("trabalho1");
$idcategoria = $_GET["id"]; 
$querye = "SELECT ID,categoria FROM categoria WHERE ID = '".$idcategoria."'";   

$resultse = mysql_query($querye) or die(mysql_error());                 
    while ($rowe = mysql_fetch_array($resultse))    {
    $categorianome = $rowe['categoria'];
                                                    }

                        echo"<center>";
                    echo "Nome da categoria: ".$categorianome."";
                    echo "<table border='2'>\n";
                    echo"<form>";                           
                    echo "<tr align='center'><td>Data de Criação</td><td>Nome</td><td>Email</td><td>Data da ultima Actualização</td></tr>";                             

$queryq = "SELECT * FROM emailcategoria WHERE categoria = '".$idcategoria."'";  
$resultsq = mysql_query($queryq) or die(mysql_error());                 
    while ($rowq = mysql_fetch_array($resultsq))    {



        $novoarray = explode(' - ',$rowq['email']);
        $numero = Count($novoarray);

        for($cont=0;$cont<$numero;$cont++){

        $query = "SELECT * FROM email WHERE id = '".$novoarray[$cont]."'";  
        $results = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());                   
            while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($results))  {


                    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($results)) {                            
                                    echo "<tr align='center'>\n";
                                    echo "<td><b></b>".$row['datahora']. "\n</td>";                                             
                                    echo "<td><b></b>".$row['nome']. "\n</td>";                                 
                                    echo "<td><b></b>".$row['email']. "\n</td>";                                    
                                    echo "<td><b></b>".$row['dataactual']. "\n</td></tr>";                                                                                                                                                                      

                                                        }                       
                                                    }

                                                                }

}                                                       
echo "</form>\n";
                        echo "</table>\n";
                        echo"</center>";                                                                                                                    
?>
```

No error line now. Just no results showing.
And i have the table category with an id of 15, have the connection table with the category as the same id, and have 4 emails, which have been imploded with " - " between them.

Comment: Please isolate the issue and at least tell us which line is 28th.

Comment: I suspect it is `$novoarray[$numero]`

Comment: Not the most helpful comment but you shouldn't be using `mysql_query` or `mysql_fetch_array` as these are depreciated. Either use PDO or MysqlI

Comment: $novoarray[$numero] shouldn't it be $novoarray[$cont] ?

Comment: This is for a project i am doing at my internship, and they requise me to use MySQL :(

Comment: Bingo @Andrew!! bulls eye

Comment: Why is your indentation all over the place?

Comment: @Heatmanofurioso: MySQL is the database itself. PHP's `mysql`, `mysqli` and `PDO` are _ways to interact with MySQL databases_. You can (and should) switch between them without compromising your internship requirements.

Comment: Also, see JOIN. There appears to be no need for multiple queries here.

Comment: @Lightness Races in Orbit, as stupid as it is, i started to do a previous website with mysqli and my teacher "an idiot" complained it wasn't what was required. So unfortunately, i am sticking to mysql :(

Comment: @Heatmanofurioso: That's.... quite bizarre! Well, as long as you go into it knowing that it's wrong.

Comment: @Lightness Races in Orbit  
Logic: I am the student, he is the teacher, i want a good grade and go to colledge, gotta be a sheep. Ahahaha

Comment: @Heatmanofurioso: Okay but you said before you were doing an internship. It's different when you're working for a company as then you have a professional responsibility.

Comment: I know, but they are requiring specifically like this. Also my internship will count for my final avaluation, and the way i do all the projects has to be like i did here. It's stupid, i know. I can do better and different, but heck... @Lightness Races in Orbit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Counting start from 0, so:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM email WHERE id = '".$novoarray[$numero]."'";
```

Need change to:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM email WHERE id = '".$novoarray[$numero-1]."'";
```

Try to use this:

```
<?php
mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die("problema na conexao");
mysql_select_db("trabalho1");
$idcategoria = $_GET["id"];
$querye = "SELECT ID,categoria FROM categoria WHERE ID = '".$idcategoria."'";

$resultse = mysql_query($querye) or die(mysql_error());
while ($rowe = mysql_fetch_array($resultse))    {
    $categorianome = $rowe['categoria'];
}

echo"<center>";
echo "Nome da categoria: ".$categorianome."";
echo "<table border='2'>\n";
echo"<form>";
echo "<tr align='center'><td>Data de Criação</td><td>Nome</td><td>Email</td><td>Data da ultima Actualização</td></tr>";

$queryq = "SELECT * FROM emailcategoria WHERE categoria = '".$idcategoria."'";
$resultsq = mysql_query($queryq) or die(mysql_error());
while ($rowq = mysql_fetch_array($resultsq))    {



    $novoarray = explode(' - ',$rowq['email']);
    $numero = Count($novoarray);

    for($cont=0;$cont<$numero;$cont++){

        $query = "SELECT * FROM email WHERE id = '".$novoarray[$cont]."'";
        $results = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());


            while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($results)) {
                echo "<tr align='center'>\n";
                echo "<td><b></b>".$row['datahora']. "\n</td>";
                echo "<td><b></b>".$row['nome']. "\n</td>";
                echo "<td><b></b>".$row['email']. "\n</td>";
                echo "<td><b></b>".$row['dataactual']. "\n</td></tr>";

            }

    }

}
echo "</form>\n";
echo "</table>\n";
echo"</center>";
?>
```

You use

```
while ($rowq = mysql_fetch_array($resultsq))    {
```

Two times..

Comment: Now it isn't giving any error, but it isn't showing any data.  
I am trying to read a registry line which is category 15, and has 4 emails on it. But won't give any result back

Comment: Awlad Liton are right. You need to sue $cont instead of $numero.

Comment: If you have no result - then you get empty answer from your database. Check your $rowq['email']. Try to do: var_dump($rowq['email']);

Comment: Gave me this:  
asstring(18) "9333 - 9398 - 9423"  
Which is the IDs of the emails

Comment: Perfect! Thankyou very much!
And by the way, thanks everyone else who also helped me out!

Answer (score 1):

it seems that below line:

```
  $query = "SELECT * FROM email WHERE id = '".$novoarray[$numero]."'";
```

should be:

```
    $query = "SELECT * FROM email WHERE id = '".$novoarray[$cont]."'";
```

you are running a loop through the `$numero = Count($novoarray);`. So it seems that you need to change above line.

Another thing:

you have fetch twice same thing here:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($results))  {

                    echo "<tr align='center'><td>Data de Criação</td><td>Nome</td><td>Email</td><td>Data da ultima Actualização</td></tr>";
                    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($results)) {
```

it is meaningless.

Comment: You're right. Changed, but now it still won't give me any results. And no error now

Comment: can you add the value of `$novoarray ` after explode?

Comment: Can you rephrase that?

Comment: remove first one and also remove its closing while bracket :)

Answer (score 1):

You created your for here:

```
for($cont=0;$cont<$numero;$cont++){
```

but then here you are using always `$numero`:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM email WHERE id = '".$novoarray[$numero]."'";

                                                         ^
```

are you sure that's the way it should be and not `$cont` in there? (The actual variable that's being changed by the for loop)

Comment: You're right. But now it won't give me any value, no error. Nothing

Comment: Then there are no such values in your database table. Since you did not provide any sample data, it is impossible to tell you why that may be. Print out your query string so you know what it is, then test it manually in your SQL editor (SQLYog, PhpMyAdmin, w/e) and debug it there.

Comment: @Heatmanofurioso I see 2 `while` loops like this `$row = mysql_fetch_array($results)` that's probably your issue

Comment: You should find out why this is happening then. Possible reasons might be that the select query is returning empty results. As Lightness Races in Orbit said, try a manual query. If that works, then it's probably something wrong with how $novoarray[$numero] is being translated. 
Try to print_r($novoarray) and make sure that it's being exploded as you want.

Comment: Have a row on the table emailcategoria which has these data:  
field email: "9333 - 9398 - 9423"
field id: "1"
field categoria: "15"

Comment: @Andrew I did a print on $novoarray[0], and it gave me the correct email id, also did on $novoarray[1], and worked fine. So it's getting the values i want, which also confirms that the query isn't returning empty results

Answer (score 0):

$novoarray = explode(' - ',$rowq['email']);
$numero = Count($novoarray);

What are trying to do with Count($novoarray);

Comment: I am trying to see how many positions it will give me on the vector. So i run the for that many times in order to bring out all the values on the vector he explode created